# HTTP Response version is different with real version

Tags: openssl, httpresponse

on the server, openssl seems like updated

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
```

but http response is different

```
Server:Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.4.3
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of OPENSSL is not vulnerable.
see this link:
https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/781793

As far as the Http response is concerned , I think it is showing the version available when the Apache is compiled.

In any case, you are most likely not vulnerable but you can check your server 
using this offline scanner. 
https://github.com/sensepost/heartbleed-poc/blob/master/heartbleed-poc.py

Comment: yes. im sure, openssl version is updated. but why server value in http response is different than real version?

Comment: Did you upgrade your version of OpenSSL manually? Try yum info openssl and check the version and release information.

Comment: yum geting **No Packages marked for Update**. i'm upgraded openssl manually. this can be a reason for http server response ?

Comment: Try this command "yum info openssl" without quotes. Also try to locate openssl. 
You may have installed in the location which may not be linked with /usr/bin.